# How to use fnmatch from a shell?

Tags: shell, glob

In a generic shell script, I would like to use shell pattern matching to filter the lines of a text file.

I have a list of file names in files.txt:

```
file1.txt
file2.sh
file3.png
```

And I have a list of patterns in patterns.txt:

```
other_file.txt
file2.*
```

If I would have regular expressions in patterns.txt, I could do this:

```
$ grep -v -f patterns.txt files.txt
```

But I would like to use shell globbing patterns. I found the C function fnmatch but no shell/unix command to use it.

Comment: This can be done in the shell but it's going to be *slooow*. I recommend you use a different language for it.

Comment: Can you simply translate your shell expressions to regular expressions?  Even automating a basic version of this translation might be better than the alternatives.

Comment: I was hoping that I just missed a command like grep which works with globs. Translating the pattern is not trivial as well.

Comment: @mirabilos It should run under most Linux distributions (/bin/sh), BSDs, MacOS, cygwin and msysgit. POSIX compliant would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is going to be really unperformant, as POSIX sh does not even have arrays (which I would have used for caching the patterns):

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    hasmatch=0
    while IFS= read -r pattern; do
        case $filename in ($pattern) hasmatch=1; break ;; esac
    done <patterns.txt
    test $hasmatch = 1 || printf '%s\n' "$filename"
done <files.txt
```

If you don’t need the positional arguments (`$1`, `$2`, …) you can abuse those for pattern caching though:

```
saveIFS=$IFS; IFS='
'; set -o noglob
set -- $(cat patterns.txt)
IFS=$saveIFS; set +o noglob
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    hasmatch=0
    for pattern in "$@"; do
        case $filename in ($pattern) hasmatch=1; break ;; esac
    done
    test $hasmatch = 1 || printf '%s\n' "$filename"
done <files.txt
```

Be careful about whitespace there though: we set `IFS` to a literal newline character and nothing else, i.e. `IFS='`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`'`.

I’ve tested this with your dataset plus a few additions (like a `a b*` pattern, to test whitespace behaviour), and it seems to work for me according to the spec in the OP.

Comment: You can write `for pattern` instead of `for pattern in "$@"`.

Comment: @AlexShpilkin only if you have a newline after `pattern` instead of a semicolon because that gets misparsed by some shells (cf. The GNU Autoconf Manual, section Portable Shell), also it’s bad style (old and inconsistent) and therefore not recommended for modern shell (besides being bad advice due to the above). – Full Disclosure: I’m one of the authors of those modern shells.